# Which DTO Should Be Used In CreatedAtRoute Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, restful-architecture

I have two DTOs for my Product entity: **ProductGetDto** and **ProductCreateDto**.

**ProductGetDto** contains *Id*, *Name*, *IsActive*, *CreatedBy*, *CreationDate*, *ModifiedBy* and *ModificationDate* properties.

**ProductCreateDto** contains *Name*, *IsActive* and *CreatedBy* properties.

I use the following code in my ProductController (Web API 2 controller):

```
[ResponseType(typeof(ProductGetDto))]
public IHttpActionResult PostProduct(ProductCreateDto productCreateDto)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    ProductCreate productCreate = Mapper.Map<ProductCreate>(productCreateDto);

    Guid productId = productManager.Create(productCreate);

    ProductGet productGet = productManager.GetById(productId);

    ProductGetDto productGetDto = Mapper.Map<ProductGetDto>(productGet);

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = productGetDto.Id }, productGetDto);
}
```

I have no idea whether this is correct.

Can I use the **ProductCreateDto** model in the CreatedAtRoute method? Could this be accurate method? I don't want to call *productManager.GetById(productId)* again. **ProductGetDto** has all properties but **ProductCreateDto** has not.

*GetProducts()* and *GetProduct(id)* methods where in ProductController returns **ProductGetDto**. Is this wrong if I return **ProductCreateDto** in *PostProduct(ProductCreateDto productCreateDto)*?

I'm so sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a single model for this API endpoint: Product(Dto)? It could easily be the same as ProductGetDto as it contains all the fields that ProductCreateDto also requires.

Otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: So how to do the validation with FluentValidation in this case? **ProductUpdateDto** has _Id_ property but **ProductCreateDto** has not.

Comment: fair enough - you didn't mention you were using hard validation against the _Id_ property